# Action not mapped with mapDispatchtoProps

Tags: reactjs, undefined, action

Hello everyone and merry x-mas
I have created and action with source code like this:

```
export const SWITCH_LANGUAGE = 'SWITCH_LANGUAGE';

    export function switchLanguage(language) {

        return {
          type: SWITCH_LANGUAGE,
          payload: language
        };
    }
```

Then i want to make this action a prop in my page.js
As a result i write:

```
import { switchLanguage } from '../actions/index';
...
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ switchLanguage }, dispatch);
}
..
const switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;
```

But when i write a console.log(props.switchLanguage) it shows me

```
function () {
        return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(undefined, arguments));
      }
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: i this is the problem const switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage(//parameter)

Comment: a parameter? i dont think so but thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: so what's the problem ?

Comment: it would print undefined because there is no value stored in a redux store

Comment: Look i have another exampe to show you i have an action:

Comment: ok let me have a look.

Comment: I think should be `return bindActionCreators(switchLanguage, dispatch);` and then to use `this.props.switchLanguage(something)`

Comment: Does my answer below make sense?

Comment: you got the solution ?\

Answer (score 0):

The output you're getting is expected. There's nothing wrong there. The line:

```
function () {
    return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(undefined, arguments));
}
```

is the action creator (`switchLanguage`) with any passed in arguments applied (with `apply`) then it's passed into `dispatch`. That's exactly what `bindActionCreators` is used for.

> According to the docs, `bindActionCreators` is used when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of
>   Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.
>   See more at http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html.

In your components you access any props like you just did. Then when you want to dispatch an action just call `this.props.switchLanguage(/*language*/)` or `switchLanguage(/*language*/)` if you've previously extracted the function from `this.props`.

Everything should work as expected as long as your reducer handles the action correctly.